# Download Notifications actions

Tags: android, download, notifications

I have an app that in part of this app downloads video files.
I show the download in the notification in the status bar.
and every notification has a cancel action button.
in the first notification cancel action button enable but in another notification cancel action button is disabled!!!

[image]

please help me.

my classes:

```
    private void DownloadMovie(String _link, String fileName)
{

   BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(ProductDetails.this);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_startingdownload);
    bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);


    MaterialButton reject_btn = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.canceldw_btn);
    MaterialButton close_btn = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.closeWindow);
    ProgressBar progressBar = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    TextView downloadingtxt = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    TextView progresstext = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.progresstxt);
    TextView TVSizeDownload = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.TVSizeDownload);
    TextView TVSizeTypeDownload = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.TVSizeTypeDownload);


     TextView fileSizetxt = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.fileSize);

    assert TVSizeDownload != null;
    TVSizeDownload.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    assert TVSizeTypeDownload != null;
    TVSizeTypeDownload.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    assert progresstext != null;
    progresstext.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    assert downloadingtxt != null;
    downloadingtxt.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    assert progressBar != null;
    progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    assert reject_btn != null;
    reject_btn.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    assert fileSizetxt != null;
    fileSizetxt.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    assert close_btn != null;
    close_btn.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
      
    downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager(1);
    retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy();
   NewDownloadClass myDownloadStatusListener = new 
   NewDownloadClass(downloadManager, progresstext, downloadingtxt, 
  TVSizeDownload, TVSizeTypeDownload, pathdata, fileName,
            bottomSheetDialog, progressBar, "film", titleName, 
 
 
 
ProductDetails.this,lat,lng,product_id,user_id,token,os_ver,deviceName);


    Toast.makeText(this, "released"+"-"+downloadManager.isReleased(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    myDownloadStatusListener.delegate = this;

    isDownloadCompleted = false;

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(_link);
    Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(pathdata + fileName);
    retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 3, 2f);
    downloadingtxt.setText("downloading");

    DownloadRequest downloadRequest = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy)
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.HIGH)
            .setDownloadContext("first")//Optional
            .setDeleteDestinationFileOnFailure(true)
            .setDownloadResumable(true)
            .setStatusListener(myDownloadStatusListener);

    if (downloadManager.query(downloadId) == DownloadManager.STATUS_NOT_FOUND) {
        downloadId = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest);
    }


    close_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
     reject_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
            downloadManager.cancelAll();


            if (new File(pathdata + fileName).exists())
                if (new File(pathdata + fileName).delete()) {
                    Log.e("DEL FILE FROM SD", "--ok");
                }

            if (notificationId != 0)
                if (mNotifyManager != null)
                    mNotifyManager.cancel(notificationId);


            isDownloadCompleted=true;

        }
    });

    bottomSheetDialog.show();


}
```

my NewDownloadClass:

```
public class NewDownloadClass implements DownloadStatusListenerV1 {


String type;

BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;
TextView downloadingtxt;
TextView progresstext;
TextView tvSizeDownload;
TextView tvSizeTypeDownload;
ProgressBar progressBar;
public ThinDownloadManager downloadManager;
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;


ProgressDialog bar;
static int i = 0;
Activity activity;
String link, id, name, path, unziplocate, state, notifName;

private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
DownloadClass downloadClass;

String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";
PendingIntent pendingIntent, dismissNotif;
int notificationId = 0;
String lat;
String lng;
String product_id;
String user_id;
String token;
String os_ver;
String deviceName;

public NewDownloadClass(ThinDownloadManager downloadManager, TextView 
 progresstext, TextView downloadingtxt, TextView tvSizeDownload, 
  TextView tvSizeTypeDownload,
                        String pathdata, String fileName, 
   BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog, ProgressBar progressBar, 
     String film, String titleName,
                        ProductDetails productDetails, String lat, 
   String lng, String product_id, String user_id, String token, 
    String os_ver, String deviceName) {
    this.downloadManager = downloadManager;

    this.bottomSheetDialog = bottomSheetDialog;
    this.downloadingtxt = downloadingtxt;
    this.progresstext = progresstext;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.tvSizeDownload = tvSizeDownload;
    this.tvSizeTypeDownload = tvSizeTypeDownload;
    //        this.bar = progress;
    this.link = link;
    this.path = pathdata;
    this.name = fileName;

    this.state = film;
    this.notifName = titleName;
    this.activity = productDetails;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.product_id = product_id;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.token = token;
    this.os_ver = os_ver;
    this.deviceName = deviceName;
    //        this.mNotifyManager=mNotifyManager;
    //        this.mBuilder=mBuilder;
    //        this.notificationId=notificationId;


    preparAndShowDownload();

}

private void preparAndShowDownload() {

    notificationId = new Random().nextInt(); // just use a counter in 
    some util class...
    //behtare id khode file bashe ke uniqe

    // for open activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ProductDetails.class);
    //todo intent put extra
    //todo check in below android 6 and api 23

    intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
    intent.putExtra("lng", lng);
    intent.putExtra("product_id", product_id);
    intent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
    intent.putExtra("token", token);
    intent.putExtra("os_ver", os_ver);
    intent.putExtra("deviceName", deviceName);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
     android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, 
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) 
    activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
        android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new 
       NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, notifName, 
        importance);
        
        
      mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, 
    notificationChannel.getId());
    } else {
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity);
    }


    ButtonReceiver.downloadManager = downloadManager;

    Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(activity, ButtonReceiver.class);
    buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);
    buttonIntent.putExtra("file", path + name);
    dismissNotif = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, 
    buttonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mBuilder = mBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_comica_about_logo)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, 
       R.color.ocher))
            .setContentTitle("downloading")
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)

            .setProgress(0, 0, false)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close_notif, "انصراف", 
       dismissNotif)
            
   
   
   
   
  .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), 
 R.drawable.ic_comica_about_logo));

    mNotifyManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());

}


@Override
public void onDownloadComplete(DownloadRequest downloadRequest) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    downloadManager.release();
    bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    delegate.processFinish(true);


    downloadingtxt.setText("دانلود کامل شد.");


    mBuilder
            .setContentTitle("دانلود تمام شد")
            .setContentText("")

            // Removes the progress bar
            .setProgress(0, 0, false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());

    if (notificationId != 0)
        mNotifyManager.cancel(notificationId);




}

@Override
public void onDownloadFailed(DownloadRequest downloadRequest, int 
   errorCode, String errorMessage) {
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing())
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    downloadManager.cancelAll();


    File file = new File(path + name);
    if (file.exists())
        if (file.delete())
            Log.e("failed del  sd", "--ok--" + path + name);
        else
            Log.e("failed del  sd", "--NOT ok--" + path + name);

    if (notificationId != 0)
        mNotifyManager.cancel(notificationId);

    delegate.allowDownload(true);


}



@Override
public void onProgress(DownloadRequest downloadRequest, long 
  totalBytes, long downloadedBytes, int progress) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    progresstext.setText(progress + "%");

    int size = (int) ((totalBytes / 1024) / 1024);
    String type;
    if (size < 1) {
        size = (int) (totalBytes / (1024));
        type = " KB";
    } else {
        type = " MB";
    }
    tvSizeDownload.setText(String.valueOf(size));
    tvSizeTypeDownload.setText(type);

    mBuilder
            .setSubText(progress + "%")
            .setProgress(100, progress, false);

    mNotifyManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
   }


  }
```

Comment: `PendingIntent pendingIntent, dismissNotif;` Why define there? Declare them in the class where they are used. I think there are more variables you declare too early. Declare them there where you need them.

Comment: @blackapps thanks.  but pendingIntent and dismissNotif are used here (NewDownloadClass )